# How to convert datatype of all columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with 200+ columns. All the columns are of type int. And I need to convert them to float type. I could not find a way to do it.
I tried

```
for column in X_data:
    X_data[column].astype('float64')
```

But after the for loop, when I print `X_data.dtypes`, all columns show as int only. 
I also tried `X_data = X_data.apply(pd.to_numeric)` but it did not convert to float.

The dataframe is constructed from a csv file load.

Comment: `X_data = X_data.astype(float)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert specific columns to specific types you can use:

```
new_type_dict = {
                 'col1': float, 
                 'col2': float
                 } 

df = df.astype(new_type_dict)
```

It will now convert the selected columns to new types

I found it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/change-data-type-for-one-or-more-columns-in-pandas-dataframe/)

Answer (score 2):

The values aren't being saved in place. Try the following:

```
for column in X_data:
    X_data[column] = X_data[column].astype('float64')
```